# EF serializes entity to json with included related entities creates a loop

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I am using EF in my WebApi project. I have a database including many tables which are related to each other. When I serialize objects coming from tables, it creates a weird json.

My EF query is like below.

```
db.Products.Include(x => x.ProductCategoryRelations)
.Include(x => x.ProductCategoryRelations.Select(c => c.Category))
.Include(x => x.ProductFileRelations)
.Include(x => x.ProductFileRelations.Select(c => c.File))
.Include(x => x.ProductPropertyRelations)
.Include(x => x.ProductPropertyRelations.Select(c => c.Property))
.Include(x => x.ProductColorRelations)
.Include(x => x.ProductColorRelations.Select(c => c.Color))
.Include(x => x.Brand)
.Where(predicate)
.ToListAsync();
```

Because of this EF query. It creates a json like below, which is not acceptable...

```
1.Product
    2.Brand
        3.Product
            4.ProductCategoryRelations
                5.Product
                    .....
                    .....
                    .....
                    .....
```

How can I fix this? I would like to have array of products but I am not what I need to change to get such a result. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
db.Products
.Where(predicate)
.Select(p=> new { p.Brand, p.ProductColor.Color_Name, p.ProductCategory.Category_Name })
.ToListAsync();
```